# how do i get a certain part of the dom by clicking the sibling or the parent element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm gonna show you the HTML first:

```
<div class="data" id="test">
           
            <div class="title"><p>This Is Title</p></div>
            <div class="author"><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="ISBN"><p>ISBN</p></div>
</div>
```

and here's the picture of the element (just incase)

[image]

i had a hard time figuring out how to `console.log` "This Is Title" text by clicking anywhere around the `<div class="data" id="test">` element (the greenbox). I've tried several ways like

```
const data = document.getElementById('test')

data.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.childNode[0].innerText))
```

but it was unsuccessful because sometimes i clicked the `<p>` tag. is there any other way of doing this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Call `querySelector` on either `#data` or on the event's `currentTarget` (which is the `#data` - the element the listener was attached to) so you can navigate to the first descendant `<p>`:

```js
const data = document.getElementById('test')

data.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(data.querySelector('p').textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="data" id="test">

  <div class="title">
    <p>This Is Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="author">
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ISBN">
    <p>ISBN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that there's [rarely a good reason to use `.innerText`](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) - a better idea to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` in almost all cases.